# Get call without form possible?

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

Hi I need to know if it is possible to have an ajax GET call without having a form.

I tried:

```
$(".edit_event").live("click", function() {
    var currentID = $(this).data("event-id");
    var currentTable = $(this).data("table");

    if (currentTable == 'Coffee_talk') {
        alert('Erzaehlcafe mit ID' + currentID);

        $.ajax({
            url: 'index.php?section=event_select&id=' + currentID + '&table=' + currentTable,
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (select) {
                alert(select);
            }   
        });
        return false;
    } else if (currentTable == 'Presentation') {
        alert('Vortrag mit ID' + currentID);
    } else if (currentTable == 'Exhibition') {
        alert('Ausstellung mit ID' + currentID);
    }
});
```

Debugging with Firebug says, that there is a GET call with ID and Table but I don't get any value back (no json nor php echo).

This is my php:

```
if ('GET' == $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']) {
    if ($_GET['table'] == 'Coffee_talk') {
        echo ('test');

        $response['code'] = '1';
        echo json_encode($response);
    }
    if ($_GET['table'] == 'Presentation') {

    }
    if ($_GET['table'] == 'Exhibition') {

    }
}
```

Just used some test values.

Comment: [Stack Overflow is not in need of your SEO skills](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/130208/143302)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get rid of `echo ('test');`, it isn't json.

`$.get()` does not require a form.

Comment: thx deleted echo statement. Used following code:`$.get("index.php?section=event_select&id=" + currentID + "&table=" + currentTable,
    function(data){
     alert(data);
    }, "json");
   return false;`But I dont get JSON back.

Comment: do you get `[object Object]`?

Comment: Ok sry found the bug. I wanted to use event_edit section but while coding I preffered to use event_select and didn't define new section.. Its working now thx ;)